# How to get current request num in jQuery ajax manager plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, queue

I'm working on school project witch sends multiply ajax request at the same time.

I'm using ajax manager plugin, here is the [link](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/jquery.ajaxmanager.js).

Is there way to get current request number?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some information in `$.manageajax._activeRequest[name]`

```
//seems to be the internal id of the current request
var id = $.manageajax._activeRequest[name].queue[0];
//should give you the xhr for the current request
var crXHR = $.manageajax._activeRequest[name].id.xhr;
```

`name` should correspond to the one given in `$.manageAjax.create('someAjaxProfileName'...`

This information might be slightly incorrect (only deduced form looking at the source use FireBug or similar to verify)